# does arch exist on all linux/unix systems?

Tags: shell, portability, cpu-architecture

Trying to find the most portable way to determine the CPU architecture of a system, be it 32bit x86, 64bit or something else (e.g. ARM). does the `arch` command exist on all systems? otherwise how do I test this from the shell?

Comment: I've had machines where it was not present (some older Linux's).  A quick check shows it in GNU coreutils, but ymmv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arch` is a GNU command. It's just a synonym for `uname -m`. `uname -m` is portable in that its presence is guaranteed by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/uname.html) and it exists on historical Unix systems except for extremely early ones.

What isn't so portable is the meaning of the output. That does vary between Unix variants.

The output does not tell you whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit. No command can tell you whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit, because this is not a well-defined option. See [Linux command to return number of bits (32 or 64)?](https://superuser.com/questions/208301/linux-command-to-return-number-of-bits-32-or-64/208306#208306) for some ways to report the bitness of a system, for several notions of 32/64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

FreeBSD 10.3 does not have the `arch` command.

Perhaps `uname -m` might be more appropriate? Even then FreeBSD outputs `amd64` whereas OS X El Capitan outputs `x86_64`, so you'd need to take that into consideration. 
I don't have any Linux hosts to test this on…

Comment: `uname` also is unreliable.

Comment: @ThomasDickey But only for the reason I mentioned? Or does `-m` not always exist?

Comment: You'd have to read through `config.guess` to see.

Answer (score 0):

On my 64-bit OSX *El Capitan* system, `arch` prints `i386`.  Perhaps you should not trust its output blindly.

Interestingly,

```
$ file /usr/bin/arch
arch: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
arch (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
arch (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

For Linux, older systems did not have the version now supplied by GNU coreutils (and some machines **had** no `arch` program or script).  That was added in 2007, [quoting from `NEWS`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS#n2484):

```
* Noteworthy changes in release 6.9.90 (2007-12-01) [beta]

** New programs

  arch: equivalent to uname -m, not installed by default
  But don't install this program on Solaris systems.
```

The reason why the comment said not to install on Solaris is because Sun had provided this utility starting with SunOS in the 1980s.  Old manual pages are hard to find; SunOS 4.1.3 dates [this as 1992](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arch&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%204.1.3&arch=default&format=html).  AIX and HPUX have no `arch` program, and like other SunOS features copied into Linux, this one also is not in POSIX.

If you needed something more reliable, the output from `config.guess` works well for most people:

```
# You can get the latest version of this script from:                           
# http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess
```

and if you read the script, there are references to some (older) machines where `uname -m` did not work as you expect.  But first read the license in the header, to see how it applies to you.